# Add series to highcharts dynamically without initial data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to add & remove data series to and from Highcharts that consume dynamic data.  However, my dynamically added data never renders onto the chart, even though the series has been added.

I have:

- added the series
- added points to the series
- added misc series settings (name, id, desc, zindex, etc) in hopes to coerce it
- tried `redraw` calls

For example:

See http://jsfiddle.net/dLovcw7x/2/

You will note that `MY_NEW_SERIES` never seems to render anything interesting, except a place in the legend.

Here's the consolidated version.

```
...
events: {
  load: function () {
      var MY_NEW_SERIES = this.addSeries({ ...config })
      var existingSeries = this.series[0] // <== i dont want this at all
      setInterval(function () {
        // as shown in HC demos...
        var x = new Date().getTime()
        var y = Math.random()
        MY_NEW_SERIES.addPoint([x, y + 0.5], true, true) // **doesn't render!**
        existingSeries.addPoint([x, y], true, true) // renders OK
      }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I know there are about 1M other SO posts that make this look like a dupe, but none of them are specific to dynamically adding series w/out initial data wherein `addSeries` has already been called and data points added.

Thx!

Comment: You added your points with shift parameter set to true. Because of that points were removed to have the same number of points in series (0 points). Example without shift: http://jsfiddle.net/dLovcw7x/3/

Answer (score 0):

@Grzegorz Blachliński's comment was right on.  Thx! See his comment above.